# Node js cluster and pm2 cluster

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

So I am running a service in node which has a node js cluster usage meaning I am running the service with node js clusters... now I want to use pm2 and I use the pm2 cluster mode.
I wonder if it's a good thing to use both of them at the same time or should I use only one of them for better performance and stuff like that...
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I'd suggest you to keep only one cluster's layer, kinda better to manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take the complexity out of your architecture I would recommend to use PM2. It lets you efficiently manage multiple processes. It has many features including:

- Auto restart an app, if there is any change in code with Watch & Reload.
- An easy log management for processes.
- Monitoring capabilities of the process.
- An auto restart if the system reaches max memory limit or it crashes.
- Keymetrics monitoring over the web.

As the processes are separated, now can start/stop/restart them with your pm2.config.js, i.e

```
pm2 start pm2.config.js // start all processes
pm2 stop app // stop app processes
pm2 restart smsWorker // restart smsWorker
```